# How to animate a propagating wave?

Tags: animation

How can I animate a progagating pulse wave in Mathematica, for example a gaussian curve. I would like to do that for whatever function I can think of. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Have you searched the site for related topics yet? Also,  please add more information and show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

For a sinusoidal wave:

```
Animate[
 Plot[Sin[t + a], {t, 0, 10}],
 {a, 0, 10}]
```

For a pulse:

```
Animate[
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[a, 1], t], {t, 0, 10}],
 {a, 0, 10}]
```